# Are there any access modifiers we can use in React for components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The `default export <component name>` statement in React makes the component available globally & it can be imported in any other component. Can we restrict this import somehow and only make the component available to select few. I cannot think of a use case for this right now but, I relate the **component architecture** of React with **OOPs concepts** as dividing the webpage into components is similar to dividing your program in classes. Hence I am asking this just to gain knowledge and make my understanding better on React.

Comment: You can't restrict import and its not related to React. Moreover, you really shouldn't enforce OOP concepts when React prefers composition (functional programming concept) https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

Comment: @DennisVash Thank you for the clarification. I will definitely research more on functional programming concepts. I just wanted to ask whether there are any packages that we can use to restrict the imports?